# magento 2 event cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento-2.1, stock

I need to detect whenever the inventory level of a product changes.
As there is cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after in magento 1.x
wanto to implemet same in magento 2.1

```
<event name="cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after">
    <observer name="cataloginventorysave" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Cataloginventorysave" />
</event>
```

Then created observer "Cataloginventorysave.php" in which I want to access

```
$stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
```

But event name `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after` is not found in magento 2 event list. How will I achieve it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This is a bug.**

Basically those events are dispatched dynamically in `Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel` in the `afterSave()` method:

```
public function afterSave()
{
    $this->cleanModelCache();
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('model_save_after', ['object' => $this]);
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('clean_cache_by_tags', ['object' => $this]);
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch($this->_eventPrefix . '_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
    $this->updateStoredData();
    return $this;
}
```

As you can see, this code use `$this->_eventPrefix` to generate the name of the event.

But **the problem with `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item` is that this variable is not declared properly**:

```
protected $eventPrefix = 'cataloginventory_stock_item';
```

See the problem ? It's missing an underscore, it should be:

```
protected $_eventPrefix = 'cataloginventory_stock_item';
```

<del>I suggest you create a bug report here so the team is aware of it: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues</del>

After digging it, it seems like someone found the bug before us: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4857

Please note that **the PR has already been merged to the `develop` branch**

Comment: thank you. it worked.. but now I want product id so I tried : $stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();

Comment: $id = $stockItem->getProductId();   I got error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getProductId() on null

Comment: @SPK It requires a fix to the $_eventObject attribute name. Without this fix the event always passes the event data as 'Object' instead of the expected 'Stock' and 'Item'.

Comment: is that event dispatched by an order or api?

Comment: In this event any idea how to get the previous qty in Magento 1 `getOrigData('qty')` can be used for it.But it is not working in 2.