# Magento 2 Inventory & price change events

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to write an observer when Product Inventory & price changes in Magento 2.

In Magento 1 I was able to find event :- cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after

But In magento 2 I am not able to run this event.

```
app/code/Company/Module/etc/events.xml

    <event name="cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after">
        <observer name="cataloginventorysave" instance="Company\Module\Observer\Cataloginventorysave" />
    </event>


app/code/Company/Module/Observer/Cataloginventorysave.php

<?php
namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Cataloginventorysave implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_logger          = $logger;
        $this->_objectManager   = $objectManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();

        echo '<pre>'; print_r($stockItem->getData());

        $this->_logger->addError('inventory_change');
    }
}
```

Also which event is used for price change?

Comment: This link will help  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136334/magento-2-event-cataloginventory-stock-item-save-after

Comment: Yes I have tried this one before. But its not working.  I have written a observer for cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after event but it does not enter in that function.

Comment: Here are all event's https://gist.github.com/peterjaap/6973324, maybe try an other one?