# magento 2 save timestamp and product qty in custom table

Tags: magento2

I want to save timestamp and product qty in custom table, when the product qty is updated either by customer purchase or by admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an observer that listens to the `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after` event

**Vendor\Module\etc\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after">
        <observer name="vendor_module_cataloginventorysave" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Cataloginventorysave" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then in your observer you can reference the item from the event with the old/new data.
Then you can add the logic in to save your the Data in the observer into your custom table

**Vendor\Module\Observer\Cataloginventorysave.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Cataloginventorysave implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $stockItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();

        echo '<pre style="font-size: 13px;display:block;">';
        print_r($stockItem->getOrigData());
        print_r($stockItem->getData());
        echo '</pre>';
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, i haven't run code because my skills but sure it will work.

Comment: I am having an issue to catch the event **cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after** i have found something [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136334/magento-2-event-cataloginventory-stock-item-save-after] please can you explain me.

Comment: That bug is patched now on up to date versions of Magento (im using `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after`) in `2.2.8` and its working as expected. Although, it seems to only catch Backend updates and not frontend stuff like checkout. The following module should be a good base for what events you need to listen to and what data they expose https://github.com/apedicdev/m2_stock-movement

Comment: Thanks, is there any possibility to catch stock update event by rest api